# Mobile Sites (Resolution and Semantics)

Tags: iphone, html, mobile

I recently was requested to put together a Flash site. Since I did that, I of course need to follow up with sister site that will work with handheld devices etc.

I put a site together which looks, for example, fantastic on the Blackberry, but the resolution of an iphone is so good that the site looks microscopic. What is an elegant way to deal with these resolution disparities?

Also, I just used PHP to check the browser type and feed different pages based on that, I didn't actually make a mobile subdomain or use special mobile code.. those days are over right? Or am I committing semantic crimes by treating it like a normal-but-different website?

Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**CSS Media Queries**](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+media+queries&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) were specifically designed to solve this problem.

Check out the article on [**Responsive Web Design over at A List Apart**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)

**Example site:** [A List Apart CSS Media Query Example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html)
**Another great example/tutorial**: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries 
**another:** http://hicksdesign.co.uk/ 
**another:** http://colly.com/

Resize the width and height of this window to see what the media queries are doing. (also, view the underlying css)

Comment: looks like I've got some reading to do. Thanks for the concise answer. Do these implementations ever feature font scaling or is it just a content/modular sort of thing?

Comment: Things will actually scale pretty nicely, because of the viewport magic that you'll be doing. Check it out here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html (or any google search of `mediaqueries viewport` or `web page viewport`)

Comment: If you've got a pretty good understanding of CSS, you can skip ahead and view the CSS of an example site to see what's going on with the mediaquery CSS and it'll drastically cut the amount of reading you'll have to do.. you might just go ahead and start playing around with viewport right away.